# Moving pointers instead of objects in some kind of list or queue in Java

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list, arraydeque

Java offers a LinkedList implementation of the List interface which is actually a doubly-linked list. If we do the following:

```
linkedlist.remove(obj);
```

and then:

```
linkedlist.add(obj);
```

we actually remove the object obj from the linkedlist and reinsert it from the right-end (tail).

We can also implement manually a linkedlist with nodes, head, and tail. In languages such as C++ which have some low-level characteristics, one can use pointers for the next and previous object of the obj object. Thus we don't have actually to remove the item but just to update the previous and next pointers.

Is there any data structure in Java with which we can have the same effect (and thus the same performance gain of removing only "pointers" insted of the objects themselves)?

Note that I would like to use a ready-to-go data structure instead of manually writting my one linkedlist implementation (and perhaps reinventing the wheel). Moreover, please note that it has not neccessarily to be a linkedlist - it might be, for example, some kind of queue such as an ArrayDeque.

EDIT: To put it a little differently, if internally the LinkedList implementation of the List interface in Java makes use of prev and next pointers, then why l.remove(obj) is O(n) and not O(1)? And thus in practice, when you have a LinkedList with many millions of objects (as in my case), it takes so long time to do this removal and re-insertion? (Same with ArrayList, same with ArrayDeque - very long time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question about why `remove(Object obj)` is O(n):

First, in order for it to be O(1), you'd need to give `remove` the actual `Node` reference, not the `Object`.  The `Object` won't point back to the `Node`.  In order to find the correct `Node` to return, the code must either search the list to find the `Node` that contains the object, or keep a hash map that would let it find the `Node`.  The actual `LinkedList` implementation does a simple linear search.  However, even a hash map would, technically, be O(n) since there's the possibility that all the objects on the list have the same hash code, although it would still be much faster than a linear search.

Second, `remove(Object obj)` is defined in terms of `equals`.  If there is a different object `obj2` that was added to the list, and `obj2.equals(obj)` is `true`, then `remove(obj)` will remove `obj2` if the `obj` reference itself was never added to the list.

To really do this right, you'd need either an `add` method that returns a node reference, so that your program could keep track of the node reference and use that as the `remove` argument; or you could require that objects on the list implement some sort of `NodePointer` interface:

```
interface NodePointer {
    void setNodePointer(Object node);
    Object getNodePointer();
}
```

that the list would then use to stuff the node pointers into the objects.  (But that would probably mean an object could only live on one linked list at a time, a restriction that `LinkedList` doesn't impose.)  In either case, I don't think this is something the Java library supports.

Comment: It seems that I have to implement my own LinkedList ... Since I haven't done this before, it is better start googling! Thank you for your reply!

Comment: I have implemented my own doubly linked list and works fine except from one detail. Perhaps you could take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196377/lru-cache-with-doubly-linked-list-from-scratch-movetohead-java

Answer (score 4):

Java does exactly the same thing as C++. All references to objects are pointers. So, in a Node like

```
public class Node [
    private Object value;
    private Node next;
    private Node previous;
}
```

`value`, `next` and `previous` are pointers (called references in Java) respectively to the value of the node, the next node and the previous node.

The difference with C++ is that you don't have pointer *arithmetics*: `value++`, for example, doesn't compile and doesn't make the pointer reference what is located at the next memory address.

EDIT:

The LinkedList class doesn't expose its nodes to the outside. They're completely private to the LinkedList. So, removing an object consists in iterating over all the nodes to find the one having a value which is equal (in terms of `Object.equals()`) to the given object, and to remove the found node from the list. Removing the node consists in making the previous point to the next, and vice-versa. This is why removing an object is O(n). Of course, if you had access to the Node and were able to remove it, the operation would be O(1). If you need that, you'll have to implement your own LinkedList, exactly the same way as you would do it in C++. References are pointers.

Comment: One question: this refers to the inner-mechanics of the LinkedList interface or to a manual implementation of a LinkedList in Java with nodes next and previous? I guess the first one, but since I am not sure, I have to ask ...

Comment: I don't think that's quite what he's looking for.  If you say `l.remove(obj); l.add(obj);`, the `LinkedList` class will remove all references to the `Node` that contains the object, and then allocate a new `Node`, where it seems like that shouldn't be necessary if you had a `l.move(toWhere,obj);` operation.  I think that's what he's looking for.

Comment: @ajb           Exactly! Please see also my edit in the question, it might help.

Comment: @JB Nizet      Please see also my edit in the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: @JB Nizet      Ok then, probably I have to implement my own LinkedList (I don't have a clue how to do that, but I guess there will be numerous examples and posts for a rather trivial issue like that). Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JB Nizet      I have implemented my own doubly linked list and works fine except from one detail. Perhaps you could take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196377/lru-cache-with-doubly-linked-list-from-scratch-movetohead-java